# Java library that has matlab equivalent functions

Tags: java, matlab, matrix, scientific-computing

I am looking for a Java library that closely mirrors matlab's Matrix functions and possibly other functions in the areas of polynomial interpolation, etc.

If such a library does not exist I was toying with the idea of building my own but using an existing Matrix or scientific computing library to do the heavy lifting - if I were to do that which libraries would be candidates to serve as backends for such an effort

Answer (score 2):

[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), one of the most used (and fastest) library for matrix computation in C++, has a java wrapper: [jeigen](https://github.com/hughperkins/jeigen).

It allows one to manipulate full and sparse matrices and make operations one them. It can be also worth trying.

Comment: Thanks Acorbe, one of the things I was considering is having multiple backends. that one could plugin.

Comment: But Jeigen does not implement a sparse solver. [I had to do it myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046585/cholmod-in-java/30526005#30526005).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following resources/packages

1. http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/
2. http://www.jscience.org/

Comment: Thanks @prashant, I tried jama a while back and left feeling that it was sufficiently polished. Would you agree with my assessment or do you think I misjudged it. Thanks.

Comment: I think for matrices it is arguably the best package out there yet(in java)

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at [la4j](http://la4j.org) (Linear Algebra for Java). It supports dense matrices as well as sparse ones. Here is just a brief example of using functional features of la4j:

```
// reads the dense matrix from the CSV file
Matrix a = new Basic2DMatrix(Mattrices.asSymbolSeparatedSource("matrix.csv", ","));

// calculates the sum of all elements of the matrix 'a'
double sum = a.fold(Matrices.asSumAccumulator(0));

// creates a new matrix 'b', that contains elements of matrix 'a' multiplied by '2'.
Matrix b = a.transform(Matrices.asMulFunction(2));
```

The best way to get the last version of la4j - visit it's [GitHub page](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j).

Answer (score 1):

I use the Colt library for matrix operations.

See in:  http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/index.html

I think it's really good and easy to use and is better than Apache Commons-Math and EJML that I have already tried.

I suggest you try all of the libraries mentioned and choose the one that is closer to your needs.